# Determining nature of complex singularities using Taylor and Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series, laurent-series, singularity

I'm facing the following function:

$$f(z) = \frac{z}{\sin z}$$

I know there are singularities at $z_k=k\pi$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Using the basical properties of the $\sin(z)$ function, I found:
$$\sin(z-k\pi) = (-1)^k \sin(z)$$

And as $\sin(z)$ can be developped with a Taylor series:
$$\sin(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} z^{2n+1}$$
I turn my initial equation into:
$$\frac{z}{\sin z} = \frac{(z-k\pi) + k\pi}{(-1)^k \sin (z-k\pi)} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!}{(-1)^n(-1)^k}(z-k\pi)^{-2n} + \dots$$
I conclude thus that all those poles are essential, meaning the Laurent development of this series has infinite terms different from zero.

Yet, my book claims that they are all... simple poles !

1. **Where is my mistake ?**
2. **How to prove these are single poles ?**

Comment: the problem is that you invented this equality $\frac{(z-k\pi) + k\pi}{(-1)^k \sin (z-k\pi)} = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{(2n+1)!}{(-1)^n(-1)^k}(z-k\pi)^{-2n} + \dots$. Notice that if $a=\frac1{b}+\frac1{c}$ then in general $\frac1{a}=\frac{bc}{b+c}\neq b+c$

Comment: $f$, as a meromorphic function, have a simple pole in $w$ if and only if $\lim_{z\to w}(z-w)f(z)$ converges. It follows from the fact that if $f$ have a simple pole at $w$ then the Laurent expansion at $w$ have the form $\sum_{k\geqslant -1}a_k (z-w)^k$